# How to access $parent or $parents[] in knockout viewmodel click event?

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a situation where I'd like to notify a grandparent or $parents[1] of a click event that occurs in a sub viewmodel.  So basically I'd like to be able to do this

```
self.$parents[1].actionTaken
```

I think this doesn't work because of binding context vs viewModel but I'd like to hear if anyone has an ideas on the correct way to do something like this.  Thanks

```
 self.save = function () {

     //do stuff to self first, then

      self.$parents[1].actionTaken();

};
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Alternatively, you can pass parameters to your view model's event handler the following way:
Change your `save` method

```
self.save = function(theParents) {
    theParents[1].actionTaken();
}
```

and bind your handler the following way:

```
data-bind="click: function() { $data.save($parents) }"
```

For further information, please refer to [Note 2 in the click handler's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) (you need to scoll down a bit)

Answer (score 27):

Or use the `bind` trick

```
data-bind="click: $parent.foo.bind($parent)"
```

Now when you access your foo function the `this` keyword will point to the parent context.

```
foo: function(child) {
   this.children.remove(child);
}
```

Comment: Reads and functions better (for me) than the accepted answer.

Comment: Helped me solving a problem. I had to have access to the `ViewModel` and also the `$data`. This `data-bind="click: $parent.foo.bind($parent, $data)"` solved the problem for me. Thank you for sharing :).

Answer (score 18):

Nowadays (using knockout 3.0.0) one can just add two parameters to the child function (executed by the click binding), the first one will be assigned the current viewmodel and the second one will be assigned the click event args.

Then call ko.contextFor() and pass the event target and you will have access to $parent through the context object.

```
this.myChildFunction = function (vm, e) {
  var context = ko.contextFor(e.target);
  context.$parent.myParentFunction();
};
```

(don't know if this was possible during the time of the other answers...)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, actions are defined in viewmodel in knockoutjs' world. And the $parents/$data are 'context'.
I create a data structure to demonstrate your need. **Company** > **Sales department** > **Employees**

You may find it in this jsfiddle example:
[invoke root action in child event](http://jsfiddle.net/tsenyi/FCFRE/)

If you still want to do this in some reason, you may also define the **actionTaken()** function in grandparents' **context**(not as a viewmodel method). But that may be not a usual way. Whatever, check this out:

```
self.company={name:'ABC', click:function(){self.onCompClicked();}, salesDepartment:{manager:'Mgr',employees:['Smith','John']}};
```

Then change the binding click event to this:

```
data-bind="text: $data, click: $parents[1].click"
```

The updated code of 2nd edition is here:
[invoke context action in child event](http://jsfiddle.net/tsenyi/FCFRE/2)