# Scope in knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is some mark-up for a list of answers in a question editor.

```
var Answers = ko.observableArray(["Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3"]);

<!-- ko foreach: Answers -->
<div class="qa-box" data-bind="event: { mousedown: mouseDown, dragend: dragEnd, dragstart: dragStart }">
  <div class="qa-body">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: 'Q' + $parentContext.$index(), value: $index }, checked: $parent.CorrectAnswer" /><span></span>
        Tick the correct answer
      </label>
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: function(d,e){ $parent.remove(d,e); }">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        Remove this answer
      </a>
      <div class="form-control" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Put answer text here" data-bind="ckeditor: $data, attr: { id: 'Q' + $parentContext.$index() + 'A' + $index() }"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

`Answers` is a ko.observableArray containing strings. The remove link is on the template for each string because that captures which string is to be removed, but the remove operation is defined on the object that owns the list.

Originally I coded it like this:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.remove"
```

and `remove` was called, but unsurprisingly `this` was the string rather than the parent object. So I rewrote it like so:

```
data-bind="click: function(){ $parent.remove($data); }"
```

which failed to change anything. Then I tried this

```
data-bind="click: function(d,e){ $parent.remove(d,e); }"
```

which *works*. Inside the remove method, `this` is the parent object, and the parameter is the string.

Given that the final form works, why *doesn't* `function(){ $parent.remove($data);` change `this` to the value of `$parent` inside the call to `remove`?

On a related note, I tried writing it like this

```
function(){ $parent.remove.apply($parent, $data); }
```

but this produced a JS error complaining that something wasn't a function. It didn't say *what* wasn't a function, and when I looked up apply on mdn I couldn't see anything wrong. What's up with that?

---

A more elegant solution to this precise problem is available from Anders's answer to [How to access $parent or $parents[] in knockout viewmodel click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138379/how-to-access-parent-or-parents-in-knockout-viewmodel-click-event)

Ignore the accepted answer (same as my solution) and scroll down a little to learn about `bind`.

Comment: I was just about to tell you about `bind` when I read your final sentence.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of the javascript too. The knockout binding context shouldn't have anything to do with the value of "this" inside your functions.